# Checkbox in Gridview in Expandable ListView getting unchecked on scroll

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I have an expandable list view. In the child item of that is a gridview. Inside gridview there are custom checkboxes.

Now the problem is when I check a checkbox and scroll down, or even close the parent view, the check is gone.

**Something like this:**

Screen checked before scroll:

[image: Before Scroll]

Screen checked after scroll:

[image: After Scroll]

Here is my **ExpandableListView Adapter**:

```
public class CreateProfileExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    ArrayList<CreateProfileFecetsHeaderModel> al;
    Activity activity;

    public CreateProfileExpandableAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<CreateProfileFecetsHeaderModel> al) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.al = al;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return al.get(groupPosition).getChildren();
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return al.get(groupPosition).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService
                    (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_profile_child, parent, false);
        }

        ExpandableHeightGridView gridViewChildren = (ExpandableHeightGridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridViewChildren);
        gridViewChildren.setExpanded(true);

        CreateProfileChildAdapter createProfileChildAdapter = new CreateProfileChildAdapter(activity, al.get(groupPosition).getChildren());
        gridViewChildren.setAdapter(createProfileChildAdapter);


        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return al.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return al.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return al.get(groupPosition).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService
                    (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_profile_group, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textViewGroup = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewGroup);
        textViewGroup.setText(al.get(groupPosition).getText());

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }


}
```

**Gridview Adapter:**

```
public class CreateProfileChildAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<CreateProfileFecetsChildModel> al;
    int index = -1;

    public CreateProfileChildAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<CreateProfileFecetsChildModel> al) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.activity = activity;
        this.al = al;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return al.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return al.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkBoxChild;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final int pos = position;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_profile_grid_child, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.checkBoxChild = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxChild);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        viewHolder.checkBoxChild.setText(al.get(position).getTitle());

        viewHolder.checkBoxChild.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if (b) {
                    viewHolder.checkBoxChild.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                } else {
                    viewHolder.checkBoxChild.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think it's the way you're "recycling" the views in your ``GridViewAdapter``. See, recycling means you have to replace the entire state, but in your ``getView`` method, there's nowhere where you're setting the checked state of the view. Try and set it there (maybe before you set the onCheckedChangedListener) and see if that helps. The check state should be part of ``CreateProfileFecetsChildModel`` which should get updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Views get recycled without having their state reset. Imagine displaying 20 items on a screen which only shows four items at once, meaning that the GridViewAdapter uses four, maybe five views. Those views take turns displaying your item when scrolling trough the list:

[image: Views being recycled when scrolling]

**Solution:**

1. You have to store everything about your view's state (in your case: what is marked as checked) in your Adapter's child list entries of the type `CreateProfileFecetsHeaderModel`.
2. In your Adapter's `getChildView()` fetch the checked state from your Adapter's children using the `position` and set the holder's CheckBox accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As it is Expandable adapter, u need to know the groupid,selectedchild,id. 
 try as below...

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Pair<Long, Long> tag = new Pair<Long, Long>(
            getGroupId(groupPosition),
            getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition));
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_countryoforigin, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(tag);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(mCheckedItems.contains(tag));
    viewHolder.textview.setText((CharSequence) getText(groupPosition, childPosition));
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            final Pair<Long, Long> tag = (Pair<Long, Long>) v.getTag();
            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                mCheckedItems.add(tag);
            } else {
                mCheckedItems.remove(tag);
            }

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
public Set<Pair<Long, Long>> getCheckedItems() {
    return mCheckedItems;
}
```

u can call getcheckitems .....